# Differentiate between the previous element and current element from the data of a Flatlist in react native

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to build a chat app using react native. I am using flatlist to list out the messages of a conversation.

```
export default class ExampleConversation extends React.Component {
    _renderItem = ({item}) => {
        return (
            <View style={{backgroundColor: 'white', margin: 4, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                <Text>{item.sender.id}</Text>
                <Text>{item.body}</Text>
            </View>
        )
    };

    render() {
        return <FlatList
                    data={data}
                    renderItem={this._renderItem}
                    keyExtractor={(item, id) => item.id}
                    style={styles.container}
                    inverted={true}/>
    }
}
```

JSON data fetched from the server:

```
const data = [
    {
        "id": 13,
        "sender_id": 1,
        "body": "Some message"
    },
    {
        "id": 12,
        "sender_id": 1,
        "body": "Some message"
    },
    {
        "id": 11,
        "sender_id": 5,
        "body": "Some message"
    }
];
```

As you can see from the above data, both first and second messages are from the same sender (`sender_id: 1`). When the previous message and the current message are from the same sender, I would like to remove the `<Text>{sender_id}</Text>` for that message object.

```
    return (
        <View style={{backgroundColor: 'white', margin: 4, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
            <Text>{item.body}</Text>
        </View>
    )
```

Basically, I would like to change the layout of the Message component by checking the elements given for the Flatlist data, much like how the facebook messenger displays its messages.

[image]

How can I differentiate between the previous and current elements by its key values of the Flatlist data?

Answer (score 6):

Flatlist's `renderItem` prop provides an `index` property for the current rendering item. You can use index to find the previous item's sender is the same or not. To achieve this sort of behavior you need to have your data sorted.

**For Example**

```
const data = [
    {
        "id": 13,
        "sender_id": 1,
        "body": "Some message",
        "sentDate": 00003,
    },
    {
        "id": 12,
        "sender_id": 1,
        "body": "Some message"
        "sentDate": 00002,
    },
    {
        "id": 11,
        "sender_id": 5,
        "body": "Some message"
        "sentDate": 00001,
    }
];

    isSenderSame = ({currentMessage, prevMessage}) => {
      return currentMessage.sender_id === prevMessage.sender_id;
    }
    _renderItem = ({item, index}) => {
        const style = isSenderSame(item, this.state.data[(index - 1)]) ? styles.sameMessageStyle : styles.differentMessageStyle;
        return (
            <View style={[{backgroundColor: 'white', margin: 4, flexDirection: 'row'}, style]}>
                <Text>{item.sender.id}</Text>
                <Text>{item.body}</Text>
            </View>
        )
    };

    render() {
        return <FlatList
                    data={this.state.data}
                    renderItem={this._renderItem}
                    keyExtractor={(item, id) => item.id}
                    style={styles.container}
                    inverted={true}/>
    }
```

**Update**

Another approach would be let the server sort the data. You can send the messages in blocks and render them with a loop in `renderItem`

```
const data = [{
    "sender_id": 5,
    "messages": [{
        "id": 14,
        "body": "Some message"
        "sentDate": 00006
    }]
}, {
    "sender_id": 1,
    "messages": [{
        "id": 13,
        "body": "Some message",
        "sentDate": 00003
    }, {
        "id": 12,
        "body": "Some message"
        "sentDate": 00002,
    }]
}, {
    "sender_id": 5,
    "messages": [{
        "id": 11,
        "body": "Some message"
        "sentDate": 00001
    }]
}]
```

Comment: Yes, I thought so too. But I am afraid for the performance. Won't it affect the performance, if I check the index of a large data set?

Comment: @Kakar I'm sorry but I can't comment on that since I have never tried it. But if I really need to guess it won't matter much since you will be rendering items in block no matter what if you want your FlatList to performance good. The best way to answer this sort of questions is to try and see.

Comment: @bennygenel  i've implemented my FlatList data like you said above, it's quite good :)

Answer (score 0):

One approach can be like this, when you adding new object to data add its index too, something like,

```
let data = this.state.data;
let length = data.length;
this.setState({
  data:[...data, {...yourData, index:length+1}] //using ES6 spread operator
});
```

now inside your renderItem function try something like

```
let {index, id, sender_id} = item //using object destruction
let lastMessage = this.state.data[index-1];
let isSame = (sender_id === lastMessage. sender_id)?true:false; //use it
```

***** there must be more performant approach than this.

Comment: Yes, I thought so too. But I too am afraid for the performance. I fear it will affect the performance if I check the index of a large dataset?

Comment: well, than you should look into source code of https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat, you may found something of your use case

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the logic in the render, you can also loop through it just once when you fetch the data then feed the result to your flatlist:

```
.then((data) => {
  const messages = data.map((item, index) => {
    if (index > 0) {
      return (item.sender_id === data[index].sender_id) ? { //return object without sender id } : item;
    }
  })
  this.setState({ data: messages });
})
```

Comment: So everytime data changed, we must loop through data array again, it's not good for performance

Comment: No..it's only once after the api request is successful. Either that or you can always modify the api to this logic.